# nis server doesn't export new users to client machines

Tags: networking, users

After a server migration on a new machine, the new users which are created on the server are able to login in it, but not on client machines (which get user list from the server). For the users created before the migration everything is ok.
Any idea of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved; when migrating users and groups, UID and GID were kept, but new users in the new server had an UID lower than the lowest exported by yp (check the Makefile script in `/var/yp` and make suitable adjustments).